# Angular2 set variable on subscribe not working

Tags: angular

I am quite new to angular2 but i tried to write a login component. Everything works fine except after a successful login i want to set the username and password in my session service (where i store the username and password to create basic auth headers). Sadly `this._session.loggedIn` never gets set. Anybody an idea why?

```
export class LoginComponent {

    public email = '';
    public password = '';

    constructor(
        private _router: Router,
        private _auth: AuthenticationService,
        private _session: SessionService) {
    }

    login() {
        this._auth.login(this.email, this.password)
            .subscribe(
                data => {
                    this._session.currentProfile = data;
                    this._session.loggedIn = true;
                    this._router.navigate(['Home']);
                },
                err => {}
            );
    }
}
```

AuthenticationService:

```
login(email, password){
        return this._http.get('/profile')
            .map(res => res.json());
}
```

Comment: What is the login() method? When it should be invoked? If you subscribe, it does not dynamically dispatch an event.

Comment: @KamilMyśliwiec i added the login method. just a simple http get. it get´s invoked on button press. The only problem is that in the subscribe callback the data doesn´t get set in the session service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is a function passed to `subscribe`

```
        data => {
            this._session.currentProfile = data;
            this._session.loggedIn = true;
            this._router.navigate(['Home']);
        }
```

This code is not executed immediately but sometimes later, when the response from the server arrives or whatever event is necessary for the observable to emit a new event which then causes above function to be called.

This means

```
login() {
    this._auth.login(this.email, this.password)
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                this._session.currentProfile = data;
                this._session.loggedIn = true;
                this._router.navigate(['Home']);
            },
            err => {}
        );
    // <<== at this point above code hasn't been executed yet and no values are set
}
```

If you need code to be executed when the data arrives, you need to move it inside the callback.

If the caller of `login` needs access to the received data, it has to wait as well until the data arrives. You can achieve this by returning the observable

```
login() {
    return this._auth.login(this.email, this.password)
        .map(
            data => {
                this._session.currentProfile = data;
                this._session.loggedIn = true;
                this._router.navigate(['Home']);
            }
        );
}
```

You can't use `subscribe` in this case because it returns a `Subscription`. If you use `map` instead, then a `Observable` is returned which can be used by the caller like

```
this.login().subscribe(data => this.doSomething());
```

This way when `doSomething()` is called, `_session.currentProfile`, `_session.loggedIn` are set and `router.navigate()` has been called.

Async execution always needs to be properly chained and there is no way to go back to sync execution from an async call.

Comment: ok clear. Maybe it is a different problem. When i log the value of `this._session.loggedIn` right after it is set it is right but then i navigate to a new component `Home`in which i inject the `SessionService` once again and there the value of `this._session.loggedIn` is incorrect. I thought in angular2 all services are singleton?

Comment: You don't seem to store the values in the service. Only in the component that called `login()`. Services in Angular2 are singletons per provider. If you provide it on a component, you get a service instance for every component instance. If you provide it in a lazy loaded module, you get another instance because providers of lazy loaded modules are not collected in root providers (they have they own root scope. Providers added to other `@NgModules()` are collected in the apps root scope and there will only be a single instance.

Comment: I think that´s the problem. So i just need to register the service with `@NgModules()` in `app.module.ts` and it should work?

Comment: Either that, or add it to `providers: [AuthenticationService]` of some other `@NgModule()` that you then add to `imports: []` in `app.module.ts`.